# Can I get an ESTA but enter on a visa?

Tags: visas, usa, esta

I've flown on AA twice from Europe in the last month and cannot check in online as I have a US visa. AA's site has nowhere for me to enter visa information so it rejects me because I don't have an ESTA (which it can check).

Would it be possible/acceptable to apply for an ESTA purely so that I could do OLCI and then present my visa on arrival in the US?

My concerns are twofold:

- My ESTA application may be refused because I have a visa, and the
  potential consequences of having a refused ESTA application in the
  future.
- I might have problems at the POE if they think I'm entering
  under the VWP when I actually have a visa.

Typically I either fly on BA or connect to AA from a BA first segment. BA let me check-in online and validate my visa at some point before boarding the flight to the US.

If it makes a difference, I have an E-2 visa.

Comment: @pnuts I'm not an expat. I visit for a week or two at a time

Comment: It seems likely that AA wants to see your visa, so online check-in is simply not available.

Comment: The way it usually works on BA for me is that I can OLCI but can't board until my visa has been checked. A bit back I connected BA to AA and was paged to AA gate to have my visa checked. Usually I can do this in the lounge

Comment: What's preventing you from applying for an ESTA ?

Comment: @blackbird57 Someone replying to this question saying that I can :)

Comment: Having a visa does not invalidate an ESTA right? I guess it would work. The airline only needs to know that you can enter the country, they don't care how, right? Perhaps you can contact the embassy?

Comment: @pnuts fair point. The only way around it I think then would be holding a different type of visa than a 'visitors visa'. Does that exist? Is E-2 one of those?

Comment: I have the same problem, with United and AA. they just don't allow online check-ins, even if you have a green card. Their web pages are too poorly designed to handle that, so you _must_ show up in person (and get the remaining middle seat...) My solution? Fly another airline. Lufthansa and Delta _do_ allow online check-ins with Visa or Green-Card.

Comment: @Aganju Booking AA doesn't stop me choosing a seat in advance, it's just that I don't want to have to queue up at a check in desk. That's just a complete waste of time

Comment: Your seat is not firm until you have checked in. You might find that when you check-in, it is gone, and you get another seat. until check-in, you just have _a_ seat, not _that_ seat. Not every time, but it happens.

Comment: @Aganju Not any time for me. But YMMV

Comment: I would try setting my citizenship to 'Canada' or 'USA' and then going to the gate agent to fix the mistake.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't think that would work TBH. The airline has to send the manifest to CBP to be approved.

Comment: @JonathanReez setting citizenship to Canada or US certainly seems riskier than getting an ESTA, and doesn't seem to have any benefit over the ESTA approach other than saving $14.

Comment: my gut instinct is that it would cause problems with The Man in the US.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be okay for you to apply for ESTA, because the visa you hold is not a B-1 or B-2 visa.  If you were to travel to the United States for purposes of tourism, or business purposes unrelated to the visa you now hold, you would in fact be required to apply for ESTA or for a B visa.

(I'm not sure, however, what will happen if you can *check in* using your ESTA, and subsequently enter using the visa.)

For example, at https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/employment/treaty.html, you can see that for an E-2 visa "you must be coming to the United States to develop and direct the enterprise."

See also at https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel:

> Q: What if a traveler has a current, valid visa?
>
> A: Individuals who possess a valid visa will still be able to travel to the United States on that visa for the purpose for which it was issued. Individuals traveling on valid visas are not required to apply for an ESTA authorization.

This implies that you *can* apply for ESTA to travel to the United States for a purpose other than one for which your valid visa was issued.

You also express concern about whether you might have trouble when entering the United States, since you will have been indicated on the carrier's passenger list as a VWP traveler, but you will be presenting a visa at entry.  I doubt that you will have trouble because of it.  I can think of two reasons you might:

1. Applying for ESTA with no intention of using the VWP

Title 8 of the Code of Federal Regulations, section 217.5 (a) says

> Each nonimmigrant alien intending to travel by air or sea to the United States under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) must, within the time specified in paragraph (b) of this section, receive a travel authorization...

You might therefore run into trouble because you don't actually intend to travel to the US under the VWP.  But it doesn't actually say that those who don't intend to travel cannot receive the authorization.  Furthermore, CBP notes that people can apply for ESTA [even if they don't have definite travel plans](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1098/%7E/esta---applying-for-esta-if-travel-plans-are-indefinite).

2. Checking in with ESTA and entering with a visa

Here, I can only speculate, but I guess that the carrier is more likely to get in trouble for this than you are.  You could approach the ground staff at the airport to correct your record with information about your visa, but this would defeat your apparent purpose of getting on the plane quickly and easily.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Regarding your final point, I won't have any problem updating my visa entry status with the airline in the lounge or at the gate, I just don't want to have to queue up behind 20 people checking bags when I don't have any

Comment: Also, I wouldn't **actually** be checking in using the ESTA. That would just be the airline's assumption. Nowhere am I asked to state that I'm entering under the VWP

Comment: @pnuts Luckily I've solved that. I have a holiday coming up and have just applied and received an ESTA for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've travelled several times to the US after getting my ESTA, here's what actually does happen. I don't enter my visa number anywhere and the airline (BA or AA) presumably sends my info to the CBP to be approved and since they can see I have an ESTA they get an acknowledgement. It is possible that that might also have occurred with my visa, but they end up with some "check docs" flag on my PNR.

I can check in online and receive boarding passes for any connecting legs and the TATL segment to the US. I've asked when transitting LHR and showing my passport if they need to scan my visa page and they said they don't.

I enter the US and acknowledge I'm entering on a visa, or now, since I have GE, I just choose which method of entry to use on the GE screen (VW business, VW tourism, E2).

Turns out getting an ESTA was pretty useful at least in my case.