# Traveling to the US with a visa, but not for the purpose of the visa - allowed?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, change-purpose-of-travel

I have an E-2 Visa which allows me to work in the US for a certain number of days during a given year. The company that I work for is based in Florida.

I'm planning on visiting NYC this year for leisure purposes. Can I enter on my E-2 visa despite the fact that I will clearly not be working on the visit, or do I need an ESTA or something similar?

Comment: If you're eligible for the VWP program, then that definitely seems the easiest.

Comment: How hard would it be to actually do work while in the US and thus fulfill the visa requirements?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/74755/19400.

Comment: I have not heard of a days-in-the-US restriction on E-2 visas; most (I thought all) E-2's are free to reside in the US as non-immigrants for 5 years. Are you instead limiting the time in the US to avoid becoming a US person for tax purposes? If so, E-2's are allowed to take vacations in the US, but time in the US as a tourist counts as time in the US too no matter how you enter.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe...

Although I have an E2 and enter the US regularly, I applied for an ESTA for a holiday and entered the US on it. I was questioned and berated for entering the US on an ESTA and told I should have entered on the E2. I stated that I wasn't entering for work, but for a two week vacation with my family who were travelling with me. The CBP agent asked his supervisor who also seemed unsure whether I should have entered on the E2 or the ESTA. In the end I was stamped in on the ESTA but he wasn't happy.

On a subsequent E2 entry, I asked the agent what I should do if I enter for vacation and he said I *could* enter on an E2. My reading is the same as the other answer and that you *should* be entering on an ESTA but it almost seems that they consider you as someone who's left the US while on the E2 rather than someone entering on it.

The main reason I got the ESTA was to avoid not being able to do online check-in due to visa checks, which has gone away since getting the ESTA. The airline assumes I'm using my ESTA so lets me get my boarding pass and I use the visa on arrival.

My advice would be to get the ESTA and enter on it, but don't be surprised if you meet an agent who is unhappy about it.

Comment: +1, good to see you back in the saddle. Stick around this time.

Answer (score 2):

**NO**. According to the USCIS [Requirements](https://www.uscis.gov/eir/visa-guide/e-2-treaty-investor/understanding-e-2-requirements) for E-2 Visa:

> **Requirement 5** - You must be coming to the United States **to develop and direct the enterprise**.

You clearly are not coming to do so. A border immigration officer will be right to deny you entry and revoke/cancel your visa for coming for a reason other than that for which the visa was issued.

You can come on VWP if you're eligible and need to apply for an ESTA if coming by air or water. Apply at least [three days](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e1s1) before travel

Best.

Comment: Ok so I just need to get an ESTA? (I'm British)

Comment: Correct. At least three days before travel.

Comment: @SheikPaul Where did you come up with that "three days" number?

Comment: @Jordan It's not a requirement, but a recommendation. It usually gets approved immediately, and you don't fill in your dates of travel. **Also, apply here, NOT at the linked site https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/**

Comment: @MichaelHampton the Department of Homeland Security [recommends](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#ta6) (but does not require) that the application be submitted 72 hours in advance.  Not all ESTA applications can be approved instantly.  In fact, since a refused ESTA means the traveler needs to apply for a visa, the careful traveler will apply several weeks in advance to allow for that possibility.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe this answer. You've listed a requirement to get the visa, but E-2's (and L-1's and H-1B's) are not required to work all the time and are not prohibited from taking vacations in the US. I also doubt that the time-in-the-US restriction he's observing has anything to do with E-2 status.

Comment: @Dennis You are free not to believe and or provide a better answer. It's a free world. I provided my sources and outlined my reasoning.

Comment: @Dennis which would you recommend: Show up at the border uncertain about whether it's possible to be admitted in E-2 status for tourism, or spend $14 on ESTA?  Certainly, tourism incidental to E-2 travel is permitted, but do you have some evidence that it's definitely possible to enter in E-2 status without an E-2 purpose for that trip?

Comment: @phoog, You are reversing the sense of "trip". The E-2 visa is likely valid for 5 years (though if you stay in the US continuously for 2 years you may need to file for an extension of the stay). Once you have been admitted as an E-2 you are free to take trips outside the US; there is no constraint on purpose or duration. When you return from a trip you are readmitted in E-2 status. What condition of E-2 status are you violating if you take a vacation immediately after returning from one trip, and leave for another trip right afterwards?

Comment: @Dennis you're describing someone who resides in the US in E-2 status. Some people, such as Jordan and Berwyn, reside elsewhere and *visit* the US in E-2 status. Such a person does not meet the requirements of E-2 status when entering the US for a vacation.

Comment: @phoog, No, I think I am describing people in E-2 status. I don't see anything in the regulations to suggest that the treatment of E-2's has any dependence on the fraction of their time in the US, their manner of living while there, or the fact they have a home away. Do you? Some of that may matter for tax status but that is  separate.

Comment: @Dennis Which part of *You must be coming to the United States **to develop and direct the enterprise*** is lost in translation?

Comment: @Dennis The word *trip* implies travel away from the place of residence.  So it depends on whether the person resides in the US or not. A Londoner does not "return" to the US from a trip; the visit to US *is* the trip. If there's another definition of *trip* in the regulations, please let me know.  To put it another way: Every time a nonimmigrant applies for admission at the border, a new determination of admissibility is made.  So once you leave the US, the validity of your visa or prior period of admission is not relevant upon your next entry.

Comment: @phoog, We should stick with terms used in the E-2 rules. They don't mention "trip" anywhere, [but they do mention the synonym "travel" and that unambiguously refers to travel abroad, outside the US](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/e-2-treaty-investors). For US immigration travel is what an E-2 is doing when they leave and what they are returning from when they arrive. The location of your home doesn't change that. You can vacation as an E-2 or a WT if you plan to travel again right after, but an E-2 entry allows that plan to change. Why would you not want that?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer an unequivocal "yes": you can vacation in the US while in E-2 status.

To clarify, E-2 status imposes no particular requirements or restrictions on time spent in the US. You are free to pack up your household and stay in the US for the duration of the status (and E-2 dependents can apply for EAD), but you can also freely travel and spend no specific amount of time in the US. See, e.g. [9 FAM 402.9-4(C)](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM040209.html). The restrictions on time in the US you are observing hence have little to do with your E-2 status, and are much more likely aimed at maintaining non-resident tax status in the US (in which case the number a conservative tax lawyer would be telling you is probably around 120 days). Nonimmigrants with work permission will have shown their qualification for that status based on the work they are doing but certainly do not have to spend 100% of their time in the US in that status doing that work; they may also take vacations and do most other activities generally allowed to visitors. From the point of view of US Immigration an E-2 is "travelling" when he is outside the US, an E-2 is free to travel without restrictions on frequency or duration and the fact that you might plan to travel immediately before and after a vacation in the US just isn't very relevant to anyone.

Note that an ESTA isn't really a "status" in the US, it is just a predetermination that you are likely to be admissible there that gets you on a plane flying to the US. Your visa will also get you on the plane, but if an ESTA makes getting on the plane easier feel free to buy one. Once you get to the US, however, you are free to request entry in any non-immigrant status you qualify for (or even several at once if there's a reason for that). That said, if you have an E-2 visa then, as the other answer indicates, the immigration officer is going to find it odd if you request a WT admission instead since there is nothing someone in WT status can do that an E-2 can't do, but a WT entry forecloses the possibility of changing your mind and doing some work on that entry. Not entering as an E-2 is going to be swimming upstream, so it is likely to be much less hassle just to ask for readmission as an E-2.

The status of your entry will have no effect on the count of days you are keeping. For tax purposes all days in the US in any status (and no status) are counted, so you'll be counting vacation days in your total no matter what.